# Is there a better translation for after-party than most commonly used transliteration?

Tags: перевод

Most commonly used and understood is "афтепати".
But It doesn't look nice when written.

Comment: One note: this is a word not for books/literature, it doesn't need to look nice when written.

Comment: Could explain what an after-party is please? Even native English speakers who have heard the term may not know what it means unless they have attended one.

Answer (score 6):

Поскольку это неологизм,вошедший в жизнь и язык где‐то после 2000 года и не имеющий аналога в русском языке, лучше оставить все так, как есть: **афтерпати**, **афтепати**, либо даже **after-party**, нравится вам это или нет.

Comment: Междусобойчик и тусовка не подразумевают, что эта вечеринка проводится после какого-то другого события. А продолжение банкета не очень подходит, потому что тут банкет может только-только начинаться после какого-то другого мероприятия

Comment: Я написала "в некоторых ситуациях",а основной ответ.Вы предпочли пропустить.Могу убрать дополнение.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is described by the term "догнаться".

> Прездничный вечер в ресторане закончился в 9 вечера. Большинство отправились по домам, кроме нескольких друзей, ушедших **догоняться** в ближайший бар.

However, that term accents the "alcohol consumption" part of parties, so be aware. So people drink on a main party, then they go to drink more after the party.

Answer (score 0):

That has no translation. Of course, you can say "что-то вроде маленькой вечеринки после основной, когда люди просто спокойно посидят, попьют чай, поболтают и т.д.", but you have to deal with it.

Hope this would help you. =)